# Unable to show re-order controls on a UITableView shown in a popover controller

Tags: xcode, ios6, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am working with a universal app and am using storyboards. The basic idea of the app is there is a text view inside of a navigation controller. After the user edits the text view, they have the option to save the data.  This text view data is saved in an array.  To view the list of saved text views there is a button in the navigation bar, which when pressed segues to a table view.  The problem I am having is on the iPad version, this table view appears as a popover and doesn't inherit the navigation bar, which shows the edit button allowing for the cells to be reordered.  I am at a loss for finding a solution to show the re-order controls for this table view when in a popover. This works fine of the iPhone version since the table view segue is a push.

[image]

Here is the segue code for the popover:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Digital Tape Archive"]) {
        if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]) {
            UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
            [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            self.popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
        } .....
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and a lot of trial and error, the solution I came up with is creating this popover as a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController. I then added a toolbar and a tableView. When I originally created this viewController, it was a UITableViewController and I wasn't able to add a toolbar.

There appears to be a way to add a toolbar on a UITableViewController but wasn't able to do it.